# Read specific region from PDF

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, python-tesseract, pypdf

I'm trying to read a specific region on a PDF file. How to do it?

I've tried:

1. Using PyPDF2, cropped the PDF page and read only that. It doesn't work because PyPDF2's cropbox only shrinks the "view", but keeps all the items outside the specified cropbox. So on reading the cropped pdf text with extract_text(), it reads all the "invisible" contents, not only the cropped part.
2. Converting the PDF page to PNG, cropping it and using Pytesseract to read the PNG. Py tesseract doesn't work properly, don't know why.

Comment: @jose_bacoy I can see the problem

Comment: PyPDF2 cannot do what you want to do (I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2). Why do you want to read a specific region of a page?

Comment: Hi @MartinThoma! I'm a civil engineer and I get the soil sourvey for me to make the project of the building's foundations in PDF. I got 113 surveys from a large area, and I'd like to extract from it the numbers that are the result of the survey. Here's an image that represents the data that I need: https://ibb.co/F02T81x They are inside boxes in the same X,Y coordinates for all the 113 surveys.

Comment: @jose_bacoy You don't actualy need the code for this, because the question is not quite about it. I'm asking for a way to do it. But here's the code for the pytesseract attempt, with some PT-BR comments: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AihpG7ozIzxxkJdWIWPxR4LdqYzMTQ?e=lJu5Od

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyMuPDF can *probably* do this.

I just answered another question regarding getting the "highlighted text" from a page, but the solution uses the same relevant parts of the PyMuPDF API you want:

- figure out a rectangle that defines the area of interest
- extract text based on that rectangle

and I say "probably" because I haven't actually tried it on your PDF, so I cannot say for certain that the text is amenable to this process.

```py
import os.path

import fitz
from fitz import Document, Page, Rect


# For visualizing the rects that PyMuPDF uses compared to what you see in the PDF
VISUALIZE = True

input_path = "test.pdf"
doc: Document = fitz.open(input_path)

for i in range(len(doc)):
    page: Page = doc[i]
    page.clean_contents()  # https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#misplaced-item-insertions-on-pdf-pages

    # Hard-code the rect you need
    rect = Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)

    if VISUALIZE:
        # Draw a red box to visualize the rect's area (text)
        page.draw_rect(rect, width=1.5, color=(1, 0, 0))

    text = page.get_textbox(rect)

    print(text)


if VISUALIZE:
    head, tail = os.path.split(input_path)
    viz_name = os.path.join(head, "viz_" + tail)
    doc.save(viz_name)
```

For context, here's the project I just finished where this was working for the highlighted text, https://github.com/zacharysyoung/extract_highlighted_text.

Comment: Thank you. This uses Python code as I wanted. I'll try it and select this as answer if it works!

Comment: The draw_rect() uses a diferent coordinate system. It doesn't match the get_textbot() coordinates. So I imported the PDF as PNG to photoshop, resized it do match (page.rect.width, page.rect.height) in pixels, and got the coordinates there.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re seeing. How did you determine they’re different coordinate systems? How far off were the rectangles? In my tests and development, the draw and get methods do use the same coordinate system. If you look in the GitHub project, in the PDFs dir, you’ll see two viz_ PDFs that were created with the same rectangles as was used to read the text. I also found that the rectangles that _looked_ like they should work returned unexpected results, and so I added those scale values to adjust the rects till they worked.

Comment: This far: https://ibb.co/Sr66vnY The code runs fine, it gets the SPT113, but the Rectangle gets drawn far away from it. The get_textbox() coordinates match the photoshop method, draw_rect() doesn't.

Comment: @GCBrgt, wow! Can you share the PDF itself?

Comment: Sure. Link for the code and PDF: https://mega.nz/folder/P8M1HLpK#dQYVwBYg-mhpoeomu9Gr1w

Comment: @GCBrgt, thank you! I found this Problem/Solution set in the PyMuPDF docs, [Misplaced Item Insertions on PDF Pages](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=coordinate%20system#misplaced-item-insertions-on-pdf-pages). I followed the primary solution, and added `page.clean_contents()` and now the drawn rects line up. Thank you for pointing that out... so many things to account for in PDFs 

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest method when you have accurate text data at given co-ordinates is to extract as a number of viewports It could be done as 1 viewport and filter the lines not required but in this case its easier to extract as 3 text windows and combine into one text output.

Here I am using xpdf 4.04 as for me easiest to define the co-ordinates visually, but you can do very similar in python by OS shelling the included poppler version of pdftotext, which uses an -x -y -W -H syntax. Note you may need to tweak my values to suite your actual layouts, So check a few edge cases to over compensate without capturing surrounding entries.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Zach Young's answer, this is the final code:

```
def get_data():

# INPUT
pdf_in = '_SPTs.pdf'

# Rectangles defining data to be extracted
furo_rect = Rect(506, 115, 549, 128)
spt_rect = Rect(388, 201, 422, 677)
na_rect = Rect(464, 760, 501, 767)

# fitz Document
doc: Document = fitz.open(pdf_in)

# Pages loop
spt_data = []
for i in range(len(doc)):
    page: Page = doc[i]
    furo = page.get_textbox(furo_rect)
    spt = page.get_textbox(spt_rect).splitlines()
    na = page.get_textbox(na_rect)
    spt_data.append([furo, spt, na])
    print(f'Furo: {furo} | SPT: {spt} | NA: {na}')


# Export values to Excel with some data handling
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('_SPTs_pymu.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for i,data in enumerate(spt_data):
    worksheet.write(i, 0, data[0])
    for j in range(len(data[1])):
        try:
            spt_value = float(data[1][j])
        except:
            if data[1][j] == '-':
                spt_value = 0
            else:
                spt_value = data[1][j]
        worksheet.write(i,j+1,spt_value)
    try:
        na_value = float(data[2])
    except:
        na_value = data[2]
    worksheet.write(i,19,na_value)
workbook.close()

return
```