# How to extract only a Rect object in PyMuPDF

Tags: python, extract, text-extraction, pymupdf

I tried the solution from this thread here:

[Read specific region from PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72916381/read-specific-region-from-pdf)

Sadly the following example from the thread by user Zach Young doesn't work for me.

```
import os.path

import fitz
from fitz import Document, Page, Rect


# For visualizing the rects that PyMuPDF uses compared to what you see in the PDF
VISUALIZE = True

input_path = "test.pdf"
doc: Document = fitz.open(input_path)

for i in range(len(doc)):
    page: Page = doc[i]
    page.clean_contents()  # https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#misplaced-item-insertions-on-pdf-pages

    # Hard-code the rect you need
    rect = Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)

    if VISUALIZE:
        # Draw a red box to visualize the rect's area (text)
        page.draw_rect(rect, width=1.5, color=(1, 0, 0))

    text = page.get_textbox(rect)

    print(text)


if VISUALIZE:
    head, tail = os.path.split(input_path)
    viz_name = os.path.join(head, "viz_" + tail)
    doc.save(viz_name)
```

but if I set my respective values for the Rect object (which do seem reasonable) and issue

```
print(rect.is_empty)
```

it outputs `True`.

Also it doesn't draw the rectangle as it obviously should. There is obviously no output from

```
text = page.get_textbox(rect)
```

But if I just issue

```
text = page.get_text()
```

that gives me some correct output.

However I wonder what is the reason that it says that the rect is empty because I would eagerly need it to only extract the text from a certain area.

Comment: `fitz.Rect(0, 0, 100, 100).is_empty` is always `False`, because it is a valid rectangle. `page.get_textbox(rect)` only delivers the characters **fully contained** in rect. Your top-left rectangle is not very large and may unluckily just cover the top-left page border area, where no character might be fully inside it. See my test output in below answer.

Comment: As an aside: rectangle definitions are just "geometry" objects. They are defined independently from any documents or pages. So your definition can be taken out of the page loop - redefining it per page is an unnecessary waste of execution time.

Comment: Hello. So {0,0} is bottom-left and {1,1} is top-right in pdf ?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Your first sentence alone does more damage than I could've ever done by saying "thanks for help" or whatever. Because the sentence "Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here" with its "we here" idiom sounds like you are the spokesperson of a cult or something. Or as if you would try to impersonate ChatGPT. Regarding your last sentence, I don't know if you are able to read and maybe, well, maybe, then it could be the case that you recognized that I just did exactly that in my post. You are just another clown trying to please the admins by playing the stack-police without any reason.

Comment: And because you are so "technical", I am asking myself the following: Where is your attempt to present a solution to my problem? Maybe the real stack-police should take a look on your uber-pro python skills.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is delivered in the following case, because none of the characters is fully contained in the box: [image]

Here the output of another page. For [image] the output is this:

```
#ifnde
#defin
/*
```